# Database Id differs from Laravel api

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Records at database differs from the one i get with the laravel apis.

I want to fetch elements with an unique string id. But i'm having an issue.
I was able to record elements but when i fetch them, i get a different id value.

For example for the product with id "5c47b3c858e2a" i get an id with value 5. I tried query the value directly, also using eloquent. And the same result.

Migrations

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('warehouses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('branch_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function getWarehousesOfBranch(Branch $branch) {
    return $branch->warehouses;
}

public function warehouses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Warehouse');
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('branches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

getWarehousesOfBranch is the api method, a simple GET.

I expect to get the same recorded value from the database.

Comment: Can you post some more code? Hard to tell what you're doing to access the `id`. What column type is the `id` column in your table?

Comment: Check the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), section **Primary Keys**

Comment: @MikeHarrison I added the migrations too. It's a simple GET call to getWarehousesOfBranch. With branch as param.

Comment: can you also add the url that you are using to fetch the result?

Comment: Your migration says `$table->increments('id')`, which means that laravel expects you to use `id` as primary key. _For example for the product with id "5c47b3c858e2a"_, this is not `id`, it looks like it's `name`

Comment: You would need to change the controller method to `public function getWarehousesOfBranch(Branch $branch) { return Branch::where('name', $branch)->firstOrFail()->warehouses; }`

Answer (score 1):

By default, Laravel assumes keys are auto-incrementing integers. Because of this, it automatically casts the key to an integer when you attempt to access it.

To resolve this, you should update the `$incrementing` and the `$keyType` fields on your model:

```
protected $keyType = 'string';

public $incrementing = false;
```

Mostly the two values are used in conjunction with one another, but there are places where they are used independently, so it would be best to set both appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $incrementing as false at the Warehouse model, solved the issue.

```
public $incrementing = false;
```